# Make Gmail automatically show images I embed in my HTML email?

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

I'm constructing HTML emails in PHP with Zend_Mail and I'd like to embed/attach/whatever some images in such a way that Gmail will automatically display them without prompting the user. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't. This is not behavior that is controllable via your HTML structure.

Comment: Are you asking about embedded, rather than attached, images? If so, you can use the `<img>` tag with an absolute reference to the URL of the file.  They'll at least be displayable, then if the recipient decides that you're a trusted sender, they can choose to have google display the images automatically.

Comment: Do not think this is possible.  This would have to be an option set by the user if gmail makes such an option available to their users.  This is in place for security reasons as images can harbour malicious scripts.

Comment: I'm sure spammers would LOVE to be able to do this, forcing everyone to load their pathetic little webbugs... e.g. NO, you cannot do this. Period.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google's [Bulk Sender Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126) say that Gmail will automatically show images for senders who have authenticated their domain:

> To ensure that Gmail can identify you:
>
> - Use a consistent IP address to send bulk mail.
> - Keep valid reverse DNS records for the IP address(es) from which you send mail, pointing to your domain.
> - Use the same address in the 'From:' header on every bulk mail you send.
>
> We also recommend publishing an SPF record, and signing with DKIM or
>   DomainKeys.
>
> **By authenticating, inline images you send will be shown automatically. Recipients will not need to click the "Display images
>   below" link.**

Google offers a page to learn more about [email authentication](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180707).

Answer (score 4):

[You can't without the user approving your imagery.](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=145919) It's an anti-spam/ anti-tracking technique that has to be off by default to work.

You can make Gmail display images (embedded into content) with authenticating emails sent.
You just make sure you have a correct SPF record, and 1024 bit DKIM signed the message.
Then gmail shows embedded images within content.

Comment: I'm aware that hyperlinking to images on some server somewhere is a privacy risk, but I can't see how referencing attachments poses any such risk, so I assumed it was possible to display them automatically.

Comment: @spiffytech: the `src` attribute on the `img` tag can (and often does) point to a webservice which serves up an image file. It's common to pass tracking information to such webservices.

Comment: @spiffytech but what would you put in the src element? And being able to reference attachments in the HTML would be another security hole: think about someone attaching an .exe

Comment: I am able to reference attachments in the HTML by giving them a content ID when I attach them, then doing `<img src="cid:[content ID]" />`. This successfully displays the image in Gmail if I click "show images", and HotMail and Yahoo! Mail both display the images automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As of my knowledge, This  is not possible. Gmaill will hide the images initially. If the Use enables (by clicking "`Always display images from XXXXXX website`"), then it will be available from next time onwards

Answer (score 0):

You can always show images if you use Base 64. That way images are embedded as code in the code and aren't coming from anyone else's server, so there is no tracking risk. Just google how to embed an image as Base 64 and that will solve your issue completely.