# How does tumblr show logo image without permission on Gmail

Tags: image, gmail, tumblr

I've just signed up to tumblr and to my surprise, the tumblr logo image was visible in their confirmation email. It is the first e-mail I've ever received from tumblr and I have not selected 'display images' option in Gmail so how come the logo image is present. I inspected it and it indeed is an image with an interesting source URL

See below:

[image: Screenshot from Gmail]

The HTML code for the image is

```
<img src="?ui=2&amp;ik=ec1c699863&amp;view=att&amp;th=13ca2239a42b6379&amp;attid=0.1.1&amp;disp=emb&amp;zw&amp;atsh=1" width="127" height="27" border="0" alt="Tumblr">
```

Comment: The answer is provided as the accepted answer in this question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728504/make-gmail-automatically-show-images-i-embed-in-my-html-email>